# Word or phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Which one is less awkard to native English speakers, a *phrasal verb* or a *word*, in function or variable naming?

**For example:** 
*Set up tracker module* or *install tracker module*.

I already know the pros and cons between phrasal verbs or words in coding. But I don't know the awkwardness in the perspective of native English speakers.

Comment: They mean different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phrasal verbs are generally considered less formal than other verbs. I don't think it really matters in regards to awkwardness though. There is a difference between 'set up' and 'install' though. Somebody else already covered this here. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/what-is-the-difference-between-setup-and-install-based-on-computer-programs